# Python Pandas - removing multiple strings in one .drop method call

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to drop multiple strings in one column of a pandas dataframe in one .drop() call, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
fruit_list = [ ('Orange', 34, 'Yes' ) ,
             ('Mango', 24, 'No' ) ,
             ('banana', 14, 'No' ) ,
             ('Apple', 44, 'Yes' ) ,
             ('Pineapple', 64, 'No') ,
             ('Kiwi', 84, 'Yes')  ]

#Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(fruit_list, columns =
                  ['Name' , 'Price', 'Stock'])
indexNames = df[(df['Name'] == 'Orange') & (df['Name'] == 'Mango')].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
print(df)
```

But when it runs both "Orange" and "Mango" are still there.

```
        Name  Price Stock
0     Orange     34   Yes
1      Mango     24    No
2     banana     14    No
3      Apple     44   Yes
4  Pineapple     64    No
5       Kiwi     84   Yes
```

It seems to work when I do only one at a time however:

```
import pandas as pd
# List of Tuples
fruit_list = [ ('Orange', 34, 'Yes' ) ,
             ('Mango', 24, 'No' ) ,
             ('banana', 14, 'No' ) ,
             ('Apple', 44, 'Yes' ) ,
             ('Pineapple', 64, 'No') ,
             ('Kiwi', 84, 'Yes')  ]

#Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(fruit_list, columns =
                  ['Name' , 'Price', 'Stock'])
indexNames = df[df['Name'] == 'Orange'].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
print(df)

        Name  Price Stock
1      Mango     24    No
2     banana     14    No
3      Apple     44   Yes
4  Pineapple     64    No
5       Kiwi     84   Yes
```

Does it have something to do with multiple strings or my syntax? I swear I'm doing it correctly based on all of the documentation that I've read. I've removed the parentheses, changed the "&" to "and", tried using lists (which I know none of them *should* work but I wanted to try as much as I could).

Comment: replace the ``&`` to ``|`` in your `indexNames` expression. Your first condition returns an empty list that's why it failed

Comment: Yep, logic error.  df['Name'] == 'Orange' | (OR) df['Name'] == 'Mango', name can't be both.

Comment: df[(df['Name'] == 'Orange') | (df['Name'] == 'Mango')].index ?

Comment: Thank you both! Of course the " | " operator was the one I thought about using but didn't...